# Foxnews blocked by ABE? What is that?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions

I tried to visit foxnews.com with Firefox and it was blocked by "ABE":

[image]

What is the problem here and how can I correct it? Is there a risk of some kind in viewing the page (other than being exposed to the site's content)?

Comment: @DavidPostill The other question does not discuss how to solve the problem.

Comment: Wait. I'm writing an answer.

Comment: Answer provided.

Answer (score 3):

#### What is ABE?

ABE is the Application Boundaries Enforcer.

See below for an explanation and for instructions on how to disable it.

---

#### ABE - Application Boundaries Enforcer

> **What's ABE?**
>
> The NoScript browser extension improves web client security by applying a Default Deny policy to JavaScript, Java, Flash and other active content and providing users with an one-click interface to easily whitelist sites they trust for active content execution. It also implements the most effective Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) filters available on the client side, covering Type-0 and Type-1 XSS attacks; ClearClick, the only specific browser countermeasure currently available against ClickJacking/UI redressing attacks, and many other security enhancements, including a limited form of protection against Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attacks: POST requests from non-whitelisted (unknown or untrusted) sites are stripped out of their payload and turned into idempotent GET requests.
>
> Many of the threats NoScript is currently capable of handling, such as XSS, CSRF or ClickJacking, have one common evil root: lack of proper isolation at the web application level. Since the web has not been originally conceived as an application platform, it misses some key features required for ensuring application security. Actually, it cannot even define what a “web application” is, or declare its boundaries especially if they span across multiple domains, a scenario becoming more common and common in these “mashups” and “social media” days.
>
> The idea behind the Application Boundaries Enforcer (ABE) module is hardening the web application oriented protections already provided by NoScript, by delivering a firewall-like component running inside the browser. This "firewall" is specialized in defining and guarding the boundaries of each sensitive web application relevant to the user (e.g. webmail, online banking and so on), according to policies defined either by the user himself, or by the web developer/administrator, or by a trusted 3rd party.

Source [ABE - Application Boundaries Enforcer](https://noscript.net/abe/)

---

#### How do I disable ABE?

- Open the Noscript Options dialog
- Select the "ABE" tab
- Uncheck "ABE - Application Boundaries Enforcer"
- Click "OK"

  [image]

You can also add user-defined rules.

- See [Rules Syntax And Capabilities](https://noscript.net/abe/abe_rules.pdf) for more information.
- [ABE - Application Boundaries Enforcer](https://noscript.net/abe/) also shows some examples, including one on how to allow particular websites that you trust.

---

#### Is there a risk of some kind in viewing the page?

I cannot find any information about the specific message you are seeing:

> blocked_categories=bc_056

So I don't know what the risk (if any) actually is.

Comment: Can you tell what it is in the FoxNews that is triggering the "lack of proper isolation at the web application level"?

Comment: No idea. If you can find out what "blocked_categories=bc_056" means then I suspect that will tell us.